# StackPanel with Images in ScrollViewer - don't shows images

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

XAML:

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
          <StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel"/>
      </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

C#:

```
    Image[] image2 = new Image[30];

                for (int n = 1; n <= 29; n++)
                {
                    image2[n] = new Image();
                    BitmapImage bitmapa = downloadBitmap(n);
                    image2[n].Source = bitmapa;
                    myStackPanel.Children.Add(image2[n]);
                }
```

I'm downloading BitmapImage from IsolatedSotrage -> downloadBitmap(n).

When I start the app I have a black image in my phone becouse photos are not visible(why?!), but when I lock the phone and unlock I have all the pictures, everything is ok.

When I remove ScrollViewer i don't have any problem.

Why this is happening? Please help me.

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
                        { 
                            image2[n].Source = bitmapa; 
                            myStackPanel.Children.Add(image2[n]); }); 
                        }

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MCD.DLL but was not handled in user code

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: private void SetImage(Image img, BitmapImage bitmapa)
        { Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
            img.Source = bitmapa;
            myStackPanel.Children.Add(img);}
        }SetImage(image2[n], bitmapa);

Comment: Problem is in index n to get element in Dispatcher. So do above solution

Comment: ok, now your solution works, but I still have the same problem - I have a black image in my phone becouse photos are not visible, but when I lock the phone and unlock (or hold the arrow back in phone) I have all the pictures, everything is ok.

Comment: try to use GRID, to hold picturs

Comment: if ScrollViewer.Width or StackPanel.Width is 158 or lower, everything is ok. But if Width is higher i must block and unblock phone to see my images :/ :/

Comment: what if you add an `ImageView` into `StackPanel` and then assign `ImageView`'s source to your `image2[n]`. Can you check this way?

Comment: GiGa - Unfortunately, it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Dipak - I used the Grid - I hold each picture in a separate Grid:

```
                Image[] image2 = new Image[30];
                for (int n = 1; n <= 29; n++)
                {
                    Grid myGrid = new Grid();
                    Image2[n] = new Image();
                    aktualizacja2 bitmapa = new aktualizacja2(n, path);
                    Image2[n].Source = bitmapa.getBitmap();

                    myGrid.Children.Add(Image2[n]);
                    myStackPanel.Children.Add(myGrid);
                }
```

it works, but loading images takes much longer...